# Handling pasting values in jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete

Sorry if this was discussed before, I tried searching the web/stackoverflow but couldn't find a right answer.

I'm using jquery autocomplete plugin on some of my forms where the user can enter some data. Usually the data is represented in a standard ID-name pair. The name is looked up through the autocomplete and on selecting I write the corresponding ID into hidden form field to later process on the backend. I get the data from a JSON call to my php backend.

I've handled select and change events on the autocomplete to write selected ID into hidden field and delete it if no match was found. This works.

The question is: how do I handle when a user pastes a right name into autocomplete (a name that really exists), but doesn't click on the dropdown option? Basically select event doesn't fire and I'm stuck with a right name entered and a hidden field that doesn't contain corresponding ID? 
I guess I should somehow loop through the available options and select one if it matches but unfortunately I don't know how to do this. I'm trying to use autocomplete as a standard combobox but with...autocomplete.

I hope I was clear, jQuery is still new to me so I'm picking up terms as I go along :)

Thank you.

### UPDATE

Well, kinda found a solution but not entirely happy with it. When change event fires, if the item is not selected, I'm looping through my JSON trying to find the term that the user has entered.

```
change: function(event, ui) {           
    if (ui.item) 
        return false;

    $("#airport_end_id").val("");
    var entered_value = $("#airport_end").val();                    
    if (entered_value != "") {
        $.each(airports, function(key, airport) {
            if (airport.value == entered_value) {
                $("#airport_end_id").val(airport.id);
                return false;
            }
        });
    };                
    return false;
},
```

I'm just learning JavaScript/jQuery so this code might look like a big pile of ... :)
Not happy with it since it will probably be horribly inefficient (json should contain about 2000-4000 rows, currently it's very small with my test data). I would much rather loop through a hidden ui-autocomplete ul that belongs to this field (which is already filtered for the words a user entered) but since I have several autocomplete fields that contain the same data i don't know how to find ui-autocomplete ul that corresponds to the focused field.

Basically hidden ul's for two autocomplete fields are totally the same:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: -875px; left: 164px; display: none; position: relative; width: 300px;"></ul>

<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: -875px; left: 164px; display: none; position: relative; width: 300px;"></ul>
```

Is it possible to add an ID or something to autocomplete UL so that I can track it down?

Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked this out by using .autocomplete("widget") and adding specific class to ui-menu.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the `autocompletechange` event.  It will fire when the field loses focus and contains a new value, even if it wasn't selected in the autocomplete drop down.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   change: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that got me in (I think) a right direction. Can you please look at my updated OP and see if my current solution makes sense? Thanks a lot :)